# ng-class offset - how to get values from the element

Tags: angularjs

I have got nowhere with this.

I am looking at using ng-class="(checkPos)? left : right"

and checkPos is a function on the scope which checks the element offset top and left to see what quadrant it is on the webpage.

I am not sure how to identify the element that the ng-class is in, so that I can start checking values. Any help will be appreciated. I have searched for hours, so please don't downgrade me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is going to involve the DOM, you should implement it as a directive.

```
<div positioner>Blah</div>
```

Set your directive to work on an attribute (called positioner or whatever you want). Something like this:

```
angular.module('positionerDirective', [])
  .directive('positioner', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element){
         var top = element[0].offsetTop;
         var left = element[0].offsetLeft;
         //do whatever math you need here
         angular.element(element).addClass(class you need);
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. top and left are coming up undefined if I use this code.

Comment: If those values are coming up undefined then the reference to the object is not right (this could be a binding thing.) I think Angular requires the args in a specific order, so I added a reference to scope. I could be wrong about this. Also, there is an excellent article on Quirksmode about finding position: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Comment: Hi - I fixed this by adding scope to the function, even though it wasn't used - so yes, I came to the same conclusion to you. I now have another problem - if someone scrolls up / down the page then the position can change, so I need this to update the class if the position changes. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Well, jQuery has a .scroll() in the API that you can look at (http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and I see something similar on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) that might be worth a look. If there were anywhere in an Angular app that you could jQuery, this would be the place. Having said that, I would be tempted to try the MDN method first just to try to keep jQuery dependency out of my app.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad question. One option would be to use a directive rather than ng-class. It would be easily reusable. Something like this should work.

```
<div x-class='checkPos'></div>

.directive('xClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      checkPos: '=xClass'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (scope.checkPos(elem[0])) 
        elem.addClass('left');
      else
        elem.addClass('right');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Zack - not sure if I was applying this correctly, but I was getting a CheckPos is not a function error. Any ideas why? Also, could this be used, and the class reapplied everytime the position changed (ie based on user scrolling, or screen resize?)