# using offsetTop with AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using ng-repeat to output a paragraph by repeating individual letters into a span element.

```
<p><span>h</span><span>i</span><span> </span><span>M</span><span>s</span></p>
```

The content of these letters spans will be multiple lines in the paragraph.

```
line one of letters
even more letters here
and a few more
```

**My end goal is to be able to detect which spans are on which line in order to style them differently.**

My thought is to use the `offsetTop` value of each of the spans in order to detect the different lines. So, in the above answer I would have three different `offsetTop`s.

I'm running into some problems when creating a directive to do this ([based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510673/ng-class-offset-how-to-get-values-from-the-element)). What's happening, is I'm getting many more `offsetTop`s for values that should be in the same line.

[Here's a Code Pen of me working through this problem in Angular.](http://codepen.io/theaemarie/pen/yOoMYg?)

[Just to prove to myself that this could be done, I did it without Angular here.](http://codepen.io/theaemarie/pen/YqxZPd)

In these pen's I'm console logging the `top` value and there should be as many tops as there are lines.

This is my first (*real*) time making a directive, so I'm wondering if I'm just not using `element` properly.

Any direction would be helpful, thanks for helping!

Comment: I am not sure wether you can this.  You could separate you array into array of objects. Something like `var array = [{line1 : ['a','b'] }, {line2 : ['a','b'] }]`

Comment: Nah, no can do w/that one. The data is actually coming from an XML file in one big string, and it will vary from instance to instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big difference between how you are doing it without Angular is that you are running that logic after everything has rendered, but with Angular the directive is firing off on each span the moment that span gets rendered. I believe this is why you are seeing the top continually give you different values.

If you add a timeout to the directive it will wait until the DOM has completed rendering before running the function inside the timeout.

```
myApp.directive('positioner', function($timeout) {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function($scope, element){

    $timeout(function(){
        var top = element[0].offsetTop;
        var height = element[0].offsetHeight;

        console.log(top);
    }, 0);
  }
};
```

Using just this timeout of zero gives me 3 distinct top values.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh. That makes so much sense. You rock.